# How to inject dependency into MVC 5 global filter using Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am registering a global filter in MVC5 that takes a dependency on a `Migration` class:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new OfflineActionFilter(new Migration("connectionstring"));
}
```

I am using Autofac to inject dependencies into my controllers and I would prefer to use dependency injection here too.
And I would prefer not to use the service locator (anti)-pattern. How to do this? Property injection in the `OfflineActionFilter` perhaps? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the documentation under [enable property injection for action filters](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters):

First remove call to `filters.Add` in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method and use Autofac's MVC integration to register the filter instead:

```
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.Register(c => new OfflineActionFilter()) //parameterless constructor
       .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>()
       .PropertiesAutowired() //using property injection here
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Interestingly, while the title of the section in the documentation might make you think we could only use property injection, I found that it also worked with constructor injection (so I went with this solution instead):

```
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();    
builder.Register(c => 
         new OfflineActionFilter(c.Resolve<Migration>()))//constructor with parameter
       .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```